# Linker error building project with Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, facebook

I just added the latest Facebook SDK code from Github to my project. Because I'm using ARC, I used their supplied shell script to build the static library. I added it to my project and made sure the static library is being linked, but I'm receiving this linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfacebook_ios_sdk.a(Facebook.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here are the linker settings:

[image: App linker settings]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The head revision has some recent changes that seem to have broken ARC builds (static library). The static library builds ok, but then when used in my project I get the linker errors. What I did to fix the problem was to revert to the previous version of the Facebook sdk and these linker errors went away.

See https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commits/master

I used the version checked in on the 24th Feb (not 25th Feb, sorry Jason Clark!)

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/tree/9acf74345bb248d698966eac9a3057a4b4be1b0f

Comment: You're right. If I would've looked at the commit history, I would've probably done the same----late night. Thanks!

Comment: I still get the same error....Can you please be more specific?
What is the #import command that I use?
Do I import all of the ".h" files or just the one ".a"?

Answer (score 2):

The Feb 25th commit has FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.m missing from the xcode project so it is not included in the static link library eventhough the header is.

1.- Clone the latest repo, at the time of this post the latest commit is: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/4e3567c40e3b7f8156a82f18e5a2f5cd18e077eb

2.- Open the xcode project facebook-ios-sdk.xcodeproj under the src directory

3.- Add FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.m under FBConnect.

4.- Using the project Navigator, make suer FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.m is listed in build phases under compile sources

5.- Save and close xcode project

6.- Run scripts/build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh to build most recent static linked library and follow installation instructions, you should be able to compile and link your project without any issues.

Better yet, clone this repo and build it. All ready to go https://github.com/alvarezm50/facebook-ios-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something whent wrong when building your fb-ios-sdk … Everything up2date and there were no errors when building the static lib?

I have no problems getting the latest version of the SDK up & running in the simulator or on my iOS5 device.

Here's what I did (OS X 10.7.3, Xcode 4.2.1, iOS5 ARC)

- Grab the lastest source files: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/zipball/master
- Unzip files & build it `cd ~/facebook-ios-sdk/scripts/ && ./build_facebook_ios_sdk_static_lib.sh`
- Now grab the `facebook-ios-sdk` folder inside `~/facebook-ios-sdk/lib/`, put into your Xcode project foler like this: http://cl.ly/1X3B203f272z2l0w2t39 & link against `libfacebook_ios_sdk.a` in Xcode
- Add `${SOURCE_ROOT}/facebook-ios-sdk` to your `Header Search Paths`

Comment: I tried doing this and it tells me that the line: "#import "FBConnect.h" cannot be performed....

Also, if I try to copy all of the .h files from the facebook-ios-sdk folder into my project, it gives me this error:
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libfacebook_ios_sdk.a(Facebook.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: What do you mean by "link against libfacebook_ios_sdk.a"?

Comment: Select your active target, then select "Build Phases" -> "Link Binary With Libraries" -> "+" -> "Add other …" and choose `libfacebook_ios_sdk.a`

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this procedure and able to fix it.

Select Your project Target -> build phases ->compile Sources
add all the .m files from facebook static library also json static library.
Now if you run the app it wont throw any linker errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. It turned out to be fairly trivial. I do use XCode's support for git, preferring to use the command line. However, this means that I need to make sure that every time I pull from git I also add any new files and remove all deleted files. In this case, FBFrictionlessRequestSettings.* did the trick.

`File->Add Files to "My Project"`

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed in master as of 2/27.  Please pull the master and that should take care of this issue.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/commit/e10bdc15b31ab23b229f1f3e77b0e8d7affe60af

Thanks!